Onnxruntime inference time doubles occasionally
I have a .onnx model that we use with CUDA on a nvidia jetson for computer vision. The normal inference time is around 600ms, but occasionally that doubles. When looking at the profiling report, I see that the there is a big gap between model.run (~1.2 seconds) and sequential_executor.Execute (~600 ms).
A slow inference (left) side by side with a 'normal' execution (right):

Zoomed in on the slow:

We are using onnxruntime 12.1 and cuda 11.4, the onnxruntime session is initialized as:
    providers = ["CUDAExecutionProvider", "CPUExecutionProvider"]
    sess_options = onnxruntime.SessionOptions()
    sess_options.add_session_config_entry("session.dynamic_block_base", "4")
    sess_options.enable_mem_pattern = True
    sess_options.graph_optimization_level = onnxruntime.GraphOptimizationLevel.ORT_ENABLE_ALL
    sess_options.add_session_config_entry("mlas.enable_gemm_fastmath_arm64_bfloat16", "1")
    ort_session = onnxruntime.InferenceSession(model_path, sess_options, providers=providers)

What could explain this big gap between the model_run and the SequentialExecutor:Execute inference time?
Thanks in advance!
